# FTP and pulling item from array want to get rid of an Empty array

Tags: php, arrays

```
echo '<pre>';
$directory = ftp_nlist($ftpConn,'');
echo ''.print_r($directory,true).'';
echo '</pre>';
```

The above code generates and error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .ftpquota
    [3] => error_log
    [4] => index.php
    [5] => index2.php
)
```

I am able to pull array in an HTML →

```
?>
        <?php foreach ($directory as $file): ?>
           <div><img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/00/02/50/240_F_300025017_Ij8RYKdoZgkfH4QReYtj3IRilVQmU1Kc.jpg" alt="" width="20" height="20"><?php echo $file."<br />"; ?> </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php
```

How to get rid of the empty arrays?

```
[0] => .
[1] => ..
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean errors? the single dot and double dots? they aren't errors by the way. but if you want them out of the array, either use an array filter or simply a foreach with an if inside then unset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove those entries with [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), comparing each name in the array to either `'.'` or `'..'`, and only keeping the values that don't match:

```
$directory = array_filter($directory, function ($name) { 
    return !in_array($name, array('.', '..'));
});
```

You could also use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) to do the comparison, using a regex that will match a string of one or two periods:

```
$directory = array_filter($directory, function ($name) { 
    return !preg_match('/^\.\.?$/', $name);
});
```

Output (for both cases):

```
Array
(
    [2] => .ftpquota
    [3] => error_log
    [4] => index.php
    [5] => index2.php
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Qe6rl)

Note if you would prefer a 0-indexed array, just use

```
$directory = array_values($directory);
```

after the call to `array_filter`.